# let Str = String(format: "لديك d٪ ثانية متبقية للاتصال",seconds)

Tags: swift, localization, string-formatting, arabic

How to use `String(format:)` in Arabic string in Swift?

```
let seconds = 458569
```

my code is:

```
let arabicStr = "لديك ٪d ثانية متبقية للاتصال"

let Str = String(format: arabicStr,seconds)
```

and output:

> لديك d٪ ثانية متبقية للاتصال

Comment: The format should be %d, not d%.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
let seconds = 458569
let Str = "لديك \(seconds) ثانية متبقية للاتصال"
print(Str);
```

OR

```
let Str2 = String(format: "لديك %d ثانية متبقية للاتصال",seconds)
print(Str2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The has nothing to do with used -Arabic- language. When using [`init(format:arguments:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1408011-init), the format should be a *valid* [string format specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html):

```
let seconds = 458569
let Str = String(format: "لديك %d ثانية متبقية للاتصال",seconds)
```

Note that it should be `%d` instead of `d%`, which means that this specifier describes:

> Signed 32-bit integer (int).

---

**On the other hand:**

Since you are working with Swift strings, you could also achieve it by implementing a *[string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)* as mentioned in [AtulParmar`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532558/5501940).

Comment: This was very helpful. I also found that when you use certain translation software to do the translation, then import the localization into Xcode, the embedded %d appears to be in an Arabic font. If you look closely, the percent sign will look different. I fixed the issues I had by copying and pasting the correct '%d' or other specifier with the correct font.